# How to restart Chrome Remote Desktop via ssh

Tags: chrome, remote-desktop

Chrome remote desktop on linux does not seam to startup automatically on a machine restart because it requires GUI interaction with the plugin. How do I restart Chrome remove desktop remotely so I can access the desktop on my computer?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1205694/how-to-restart-chrome-remote-desktop-from-command-line

Comment: @jamesdlin looks like they made it a proper service finally...

Answer (score 1):

You can restart chrome-remote-desktop via ssh using X.

You must have an X server installed locally to render chrome for you.

```
ssh -Y user@server 
google-chrome
```

Or if chrome is already running:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome2/
```

At that point you will have a chrome available rendered locally in X. If this is the first time you will need to login to chrome and let your extensions sync. If remote desktop does not show up just visit the extension page in chrome and open the extension. Then you should have a Remote Desktop Extension setting page open and you can restart.